# Can't change plan | Stripe

Tags: node.js, express, stripe-payments

**EDIT** [Project repo](https://github.com/joshk132/asset-management)

I am using a boiler plate and have logged the issue with the creator but was hoping for help sooner. My issue is that when I go to change plans it tells me to please add a card before choosing a plan. The code for the page is as follows:

The form:

```
`<form {% if !user.stripe.last4 %}id="cardForm"{% endif %} 
action="/user/plan" method="POST" class="form-horizontal">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="plan" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Plan</label>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      {% for plan in plans %}
        <div class="radio">
          <label>
            <input type="radio" {% if user.stripe.plan == loop.key 
%}checked{% endif %} name="plan" value="{{loop.key}}" data-toggle="radio">
            <span>{{plan.name}} - ${{plan.price}}</span>
          </label>
        </div>
      {% endfor %}
    </div>
  </div>
  {% if !user.stripe.last4 %}
  <div id="cardWrapper">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">Test Card Info</label>
      <div class="col-sm-7">
        <div class="form-control-static">4242424242424242, 11/19, 123 - <a 
href="https://stripe.com/docs/testing">additional test info</a></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">Card Number</label>
      <div class="col-sm-4">
        <input id="card-num" type="text" class="form-control">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">Card Details</label>
      <div class="col-sm-4">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-xs-4">
            <input id="card-month" type="text" size="2" maxlength="2" 
class="form-control" placeholder="MM">
          </div>
          <div class="col-xs-4">
            <input id="card-year"  type="text" size="2" maxlength="2" 
class="form-control" placeholder="YY">
          </div>
          <div class="col-xs-4">
            <input id="card-cvc" type="text" size="3" maxlength="3" 
class="form-control" placeholder="CVC">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <div class="col-sm-6">
        <div id="cardFormError" class="alert alert-danger hidden" 
role="alert">
          <p>{{error}}</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  {% endif %}
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-sm-offset-3 col-sm-4">
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Update Plan</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>`
```

Calls the route /user/plan

```
app.post('/user/plan',
    setRedirect({auth: '/', success: '/billing', failure: '/billing'}),
    isAuthenticated,
    users.postPlan);
```

users.postPlan is the issue I think:

```
exports.postPlan = function(req, res, next){
  var plan = req.body.plan;
  var stripeToken = null;

  if(plan){
    plan = plan.toLowerCase();
  }

  if(req.user.stripe.plan == plan){
    req.flash('info', {msg: 'The selected plan is the same as the current plan.'});
    return res.redirect(req.redirect.success);
  }

  if(req.body.stripeToken){
    stripeToken = req.body.stripeToken;
  }

  if(!req.user.stripe.last4 && !req.body.stripeToken){
    req.flash('errors', {msg: 'Please add a card to your account before choosing a plan.'});
    return res.redirect(req.redirect.failure);
  }

  User.findById(req.user.id, function(err, user) {
    if (err) return next(err);

    user.setPlan(plan, stripeToken, function (err) {
      var msg;

      if (err) {
        if(err.code && err.code == 'card_declined'){
          msg = 'Your card was declined. Please provide a valid card.';
        } else if(err && err.message) {
          msg = err.message;
        } else {
          msg = 'An unexpected error occurred.';
        }

        req.flash('errors', { msg:  msg});
        return res.redirect(req.redirect.failure);
      }
      req.flash('success', { msg: 'Plan has been updated.' });
      res.redirect(req.redirect.success);
    });
  });
};
```

This is the code I think that somewhere is messed up. If there appear to be more I can include let me know. I am not sure which section of code the issue lays in but I think it is the users.postPlan but I don't know enough about node to tell.

Comment: I can see in the last block of code that the error is coming from the `if(!req.user.stripe.last4 && !req.body.stripeToken)` line but how do I check to make sure it is working and where it is failing?

Comment: I have tried console.log with the two pieces of data in the if statement. I also tried a string console.log and none printed out. It seems as if the if is not running all the code.

Answer (score 0):

I'd be tempted to confirm that `user.stripe.last4` has something in it; that seems to be why it's routing you to the card form.

Comment: Routing me to the card form? The form is the form to select the plan then input the card data. It should go to the form then update after the plan switch to the form (which is /billing) again to show the change.